# Spring data JPA findFirst,findTop doesnt work

Tags: spring-data-jpa

According to [section 3.4.5](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result) of the Spring Data JPA documentation, the results of a query method can be limited by using the keyword `first` and `top`.

I have written my code like this:

```
SysPrefixName findFirstByTableName(String tableName);
```

However, I get this error when I run the code:

> result returns more than one elements; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements

Any help on resolving this will be appreciated.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: SysPrefixName findFirstByTableName(String tableName);List<SysPrefixName> findFirst2ByTableName(String tableName); it works in demo but in my application the method generate wrong query sqls. they are all translate into "select from .."whitout 'top(1),top(2)'. so i encounter an exception

Comment: Which Spring Data version are you using?

Comment: Spring Data JPA 1.6.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The support for those keywords was introduced in Spring Data JPA 1.7. See [this ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-551) for details.

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me:

```
public interface CashierRepository extends CrudRepository<Cashier, Integer>{
    List<Cashier> findAllByOrderByCashiergrouping();    
    Cashier findFirstBy();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are spring in built data source, add property :

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

if you are using custom data source :

You have to add the property as properties map in your data source bean:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean    sqlServerEntityManagerFactory() {
HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

properties.put("hibernate.dialect", 
"org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new 
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
factoryBean.setDataSource(sqlServerDataSource());
factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
factoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
return factoryBean;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you did not specify a number (e.g. findFirst10ByTableName) then a result size of 1 is expected. But since your query returned multiple results then you get the error as your return object may not be a Collection/List object that can be mapped from return result set.

Comment: This explanation is incorrect.  `findFirst` and `findTop` will automatically filter the results down to the one at the top of the result set. Download [my sample application](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/35623635) and run the unit tests to see this working.

Comment: here's any excerpt from the reference documentation "The results of query methods can be limited via the keywords first or top, which can be used interchangeably. An optional numeric value can be appended to top/first to specify the maximum result size to be returned. If the number is left out, a result size of 1 is assumed."

Comment: I understand what you are referring to but your assumption that `findFirst` will lead to an exception if it actually encounters multiple records is incorrect.  I created a sample specifically to demonstrate this erroneous conclusion.

Comment: good catch! i have only assumed that because of the exception you had.

Comment: i know what you mean, and i think so. i downloaded  the sample it works fine.when i change datasource to SQLServer 2008 the method: findFirst1By.. findFirst2By.. generate sql querys: select top(1) from ,top(2) from. that's what i want. BUT, in my own application .the methods named 'Entity findTopBy.. ,List<Entity> findTop2..',they are all translated into ‘select   from..’, the word 'top()' is missing ,so i got the exception "NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements". I don't know why it works in demo but fails in my app

Comment: @phxism can you post a sample application somewhere?  The query generation is built into Spring Data JPA and is independent of the actual database used so what you are encountering should not happen.